# useradd where account name is a number

Tags: useradd, sles

Can I use useradd in SLES 11 where a username is just a number (didn't see anything in the man useradd(8) )?

currently getting:

```
useradd: Invalid account name: `9999'
```

The alternative is manually editing /etc/passwd, correct?

And then, what should I do to make the home directory?

<sub>Feel free to comment why this is a bad idea; because I'm unclear on that too. I'm just supporting legacy users</sub>

Comment: No, you can't have all-numeric usernames.  For all intents and purposes, all-numeric names are UIDs.

Comment: @sato, I don't think that is entirely true - all numeric usernames work; it's probably important to make sure they match the UID.  Adding them to passwd manually works; they work with ldap too.

Comment: Nope, they don't.  Assume user 100 with UID 200, and user 200 with UID 100.  What happens when you `chown 100 file`?

Comment: @sato,  OK, I see what you're saying today.  I didn't mean "every" numeric username works. I mean usernames with all numbers work (i.e. greater than or equal to 1000).  I need to use hyphens more.

Answer (score 2):

`Can I use useradd in SLES 11 where a username is just a number?`

No, you can't. See pablo's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949667/what-are-the-real-rules-for-linux-usernames-on-centos-6-and-rhel-6)

`The alternative is manually editing /etc/passwd, correct?`

Correct, edit `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`, but it's a bad idea to use numbers as usernames as infixed points out. You can use names like user1234, user5678 if you like.

`And then, what should I do to make the home directory?`

`mkdir /home/whatever`

`chown whatever:whatever /home/whatever`

Don't forget to initialize password with `passwd whatever`.

Comment: Assume user 100 with UID 200, and user 200 with UID 100. What happens when you `chown 100 file`?

Comment: 100 isn't a valid username, see the link in answer for explaination.

Comment: @sato, probably why we take every precaution to keep names and UIDs in sync (and not use numeric username anymore)

Comment: SLES has a `mkhomedir_helper` which is handy in this case usermod -m would copy the skeleton to the users home dir (if it worked in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

A symbolic user name consisting of solely digits would make commands like `chown` problematic, because the OWNER or GROUP argument of that command can be either symbolic or numeric, and a symbolic name consisting of only digits could be difficult to parse correctly

A few lines in `/etc/passwd` like

```
 123:x:100:100::/home/123:/bin/bash
 user:x:123:123::/home/user:/bin/bash
```

And then a command like `chown 123 somefile` may not be resolved correctly

So even if you do it by editing `/etc/passwd`, it is a bad idea