# Create Unicode Login In *Unix

Tags: users, unicode, useradd

I want to create Unicode logins for *Unix flavor OS, 
when i use useradd like below, I got that user name is invalid

```
[root@mail ~]# useradd ياسين
useradd: invalid user name 'ياسين
```

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340108/useradd-where-account-name-is-a-number

Comment: Linux is one of the unix flavors and I could not add unix as a tag , that is why i use linux

Comment: Deleted to avoid any confusions

Comment: It works for me on debian 10 (buster). If you're using some ancient system, you could only use ascii, of course.

Comment: Please mention the exact name and versions of the systems you're using. You may also try simply `useradd -m yaseen` and then edit the user name back to 'ياسين'  inside `/etc/passwd` with `vipw` (just tried it centos7 -- where `useradd` rejects any non-ascii lowercase usernames). `ssh`, `su`, `passwd` should have no trouble dealing with the username afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Check your systems documentation on what usernames are allowed. Eg.:

```
man useradd
```

On my Debian 10 in the section CAVEATS there I read this:

> It is usually recommended to only use usernames that begin with a
>   lower case letter or an underscore, followed by lower case letters,
>   digits, underscores, or dashes. They can end with a dollar sign. In
>   regular expression terms: [a-z_][a-z0-9_-]*[$]?
>
> On Debian, the only constraints are that usernames must neither start
>   with a dash ('-') nor plus ('+') nor tilde ('~') nor contain a colon
>   (':'), a comma (','), or a whitespace (space: ' ', end of line: '\n',
>   tabulation: '\t', etc.). Note that using a slash ('/') may break the
>   default algorithm for the definition of the user's home directory.

Comment: I'm on linux mint, have the same section on man useradd, and I could create the user.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Interesting. I've not tested on mine, just giving a hint.

Comment: That is why I am asking how to create Unicode user not ASCII user !!

Comment: @Eng..Abdalmonem If your system doesn't allow it then you can't.

Comment: Is there a work around ?

Comment: @Eng..Abdalmonem Maybe something like LDAP?

Comment: What I am trying to do is, Email Address Internationalization Environment so I need to have account in Unicode and not just an English accounts

Comment: @Eng..Abdalmonem You should include this information in your question. You can edit it. I don't konw what that is, so if that's no standard name, also explain what you mean.